# Why does textarea limit entry to maxlength in UI but return SQL error when entering exact amount?

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

In this ASP.NET C# backend project, on an .ascx page, a `textarea` is serving as an input field to save text to a column in SQL Server that is `nvarchar(3000)`. The standard way to limit characters in this project is to use `MaxLength` attribute. I have set the `MaxLength="3000"`, but when the user attempts to save the update, an error message is returned unless the character count is 2999 or below.

This is an ancient application that will soon be sunset so I'm basically keeping it on life support but want to understand what's happening here. My workaround is to set `MaxLength="2999"` at the moment.

Error (with business info omitted):

> could not update: [TableName.Object][SQL: UPDATE] elt.[Object] SET columnName =?, otherColumnName=?, etc....

Comment: Ultimately the update must be more than 3000 chars, maybe there is a line terminator or similar? If you set a breakpoint at the point you attempt the update you can inspect the actual string you are using and will most likely find it is 3001 chars.

Comment: The actual error would be helpful - was it something like String or binary data would be truncated? Maybe the pasted text contains linefeed-based line breaks that get translated to CR-LF pairs by the browser when posting. Could the text contain emoji characters or other extended Unicode characters? C# strings and SQL nvarchar types are UTF-16 encoded, so a single extended Unicode character can require multiple 16-bit words to encode.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for line-breaks (when user hits "enter")... They post TWO characters (CR LF) while "maxlength" counts them as ONE!...